# Mobile App testing with Appium with WebdriverIO with Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, automated-tests, appium

My company is creating a new mobile app and it seems that part of the tech stack will involve the use of flutter.

I  want to use appium with webdriverIO because it a great tool to run my automated tests.

Is this possible with flutter?

Has anyone used flutter before and what were your opinions?

Answer (score 2):

So I tried using appium and various other testing platforms like Selenium or Cypress. None of them helped me with the Automation Tests.

Though, Recently came across a github project, [flutter_convenient_test](https://github.com/fzyzcjy/flutter_convenient_test), I not only helped be automate the tests but also helped me with the Assertions.

Here's a way of doing it perfectly.

```
await t.get(find.byTooltip('Home Page')).tap();
```

So here, so may need to add tooltip to each widget(also custom widgets you use), and then run this on the above platform.

OR you can use the Text widget if you have a Text heavy app.

```
await t.get(find.text('Add Account')).should(findsOneWidget);
```